# Rails Full Text Search with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been trying to get full text search working. I want a search term like "sony speakers" to check over two fields on my product model. One of the fields is called manufacturer and the other is description.

I tried this

```
product.where('manufacturer @@ :q or description @@ :q', q: term)
```

I want it to check if sony or speakers exists in manufactuer or description and return the records.